# How to dynamically print the checkbox along with its value in BI publisher reports

Tags: bi-publisher

Can any one please suggest me the procedure on how to dynamically print the checkbox along with its value in BI publisher reports(PDF format)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

- You can can make a small table with 1 cell only , then configure its properties to be suitable to use as check box with repeating rows.
- Don't forget to use conditional Formatting as u want to make sense.